# How to work with facebook video player api

Tags: jquery, facebook

I'm trying to play facebook video using facebook video player api. I have added video inside a bootstrap modal and also I have to handle multiple videos in the same way. Here is the code that i have tried.

```
<script>
var my_video_player;
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '2xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v2.5'
  });

  // Get Embedded Video Player API Instance

  FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.ready', function(msg) {
    if (msg.type === 'video' && msg.id === '<?php echo $post_id;?>') {

       my_video_player = msg.instance;

      }
  });
   };



(function(d, s, id){
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


  </script>

  <script>     
  jQuery(document).on('show.bs.modal','#myModal<?php echo $post_id;?>', 
  function () {

        my_video_player.play();
        console.log('play_vid<?php echo $post_id;?>');
    }
  });
 </script>
```

But this not working correctly. Can anyone help me to solve my problem? How to work with facebook video player api correctly?

Comment: what means "not working correctly"? any debug info for us? errors in the console? where is your video player element?

Comment: @luschn I have added player inside a bootstrap modal. I want to play when the modal is pop up. But now it's not playing.

Comment: any errors in the console? please add debug info, if there is any.

Comment: @luschn I haven't got any errors

Comment: @luschn this method is working for only one video. When i use multiple videos it's not wotking

Comment: You might need to call FB.XFBML.parse after switching videos.

Comment: @CBroe is it possible to load that function with  `jQuery(document).on()` function

Comment: you just need to use it when the new videos is in the DOM, and when the js sdk is loaded. but why not skip jquery completely? there is usually a native way to do things without jquery.

Comment: @luschn how to do that without jquery/ javascript?

Comment: addEventListener, for example. you really do not need jquery for anything, except for plugins written for jquery.

Comment: @luschn  yes that is the solution. I have fixed my problem by combining both answers (CBore and luschn). Thank you.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you very much that is the solution.

Comment: you should add the finished/working solution as answer and accept it